# Stop script loading permanently - Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When I use Chrome DevTools, under the **Sources** tab it shows all the js scripts that executed. I want to be able to disable one script from executing even when I refresh the page. Any ideas how to force DevTools to permanently disable a script from loading?

Comment: Likely not possible. However perhaps TamperMonkey can do it - or adblock

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/278590/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-specific-js-script-from-a-specific-website

Comment: @mplungjan AdBlock is a good suggestion. There's a lot of hidden functionality in there.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question as it is scoped to the DevTools usage and not extensions to browsers. It also is possible in some cases, which is valuable information for debugging purposes. Please reopen the issue so developers can learn how to achieve this task using their provided tools instead of needing extensions to do their jobs.